# Hide site contents from visitors

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, communication-site, restricted-access

I have a communication site. I want to hide site content from a few visitors. Just want to provide them access to view home pages only. For this I used Restricted Read permission. But user with Restricted Read permission is able to see site contents and other pages also. It is behaving like normal Read permission.
 
Anyone having idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you could copy the Read permission level and then remove the “View Application Pages” from the copied Read permission level.

Grant the copied Read permission level to the user, then the user cannot access the site contents.

Comment: The permission level I created had only view page and open permissions selected. It is the least permission required to open the website. Still user is able to access site content. It always used to work in on premise. But not working in online.